# How to use console log inside a react form component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to figure out how to communicate with a react form so that I can give it an object.id to update.

I can console.log the object.id inside the update button, and inside the modal generally, but I am trying to figure out if I have properly communicated that value to the form that is opened when the edit button is clicked. I can't find a way to format the request to use console.log inside that form component. I am trying as follows:

```
<Button>
    aria-label='Update Issue Group'
    // onClick={modalPropsUpdate.onOpen}
    onClick={() => {
      setSelectedIssueGroup(issueGroup)
      modalPropsUpdate.onOpen()
    }}
    _hover={{
      backgroundColor: "brand.blue",
      color: "brand.white",
    }}
    />
    {  console.log("update knows what the issuegroup is", selectedIssueGroup)}
    <Modal {...modalPropsUpdate } title="Update Issue Group"  >

        <AdminUpdateIssueGroupForm
            onClose={modalPropsUpdate.onClose}
            issueGroup ={selectedIssueGroup}
            // what is the format to ask to console log the value of issueGroup at this point?  
        />
        {console.log("issueGroup inside modal", selectedIssueGroup )}
    </Modal>
</Button>
```

I have tried adding {} and () and cannot find a format that works.

I tried using async await's suggestion below. I can use it to check each of the lines marked 1 and 2 but (and those logs do record the issueGroup) but I cannot use it as a child where shown in 3. That form component wont accept children. Is there a way to check that the issueGroup is known inside the form component?

```
const CheckIfModalKnowsIssueGroupId = props => {
  console.log("checking if modal knows the issue group", props.toLog);
  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

 {  console.log("update knows what the issuegroup is", selectedIssueGroup)}
```

// If I try using this check above the modal as position #1, I can see that the log records the issueGroup 


<Modal {...modalPropsUpdate } title="Update Issue Group"  >

// If I try using this as position #2 (above the form), I can see that the log records the issueGroup

```
   <CheckIfModalKnowsIssueGroupId toLog={selectedIssueGroup}>


<AdminUpdateIssueGroupForm 
                                      onClose={modalPropsUpdate.onClose} 
                                      issueGroup ={selectedIssueGroup} 
                                >
```

// If I refactor this to try and make the CheckIfModalKnowsIssueGroupId a child of the form, the console does not log anything

{console.log("issueGroup inside modal", selectedIssueGroup )}

ALTERNATE for attempt to log in position #3

```
<AdminUpdateIssueGroupForm 
 onClose={modalPropsUpdate.onClose} 
 issueGroup ={selectedIssueGroup} 
>
  <CheckIfModalKnowsIssueGroupId toLog={selectedIssueGroup} />
    
</AdminUpdateIssueGroupForm>
```

Comment: You're trying to run js inside jsx, instead you should execute the log before the component is rendered. So you could create a custom component, which is basically a wrapper to your `Modal` component, with the added functionality of logging the variable.

Comment: Is there anything that explains that in english? I am very slow to learn - 10 years into trying and I still can't make sense of what you have just said. Are you saying I should make a component called checkTheValueOfSelectedIssueGroup and then define console log inside that and then put the form inside that function? Wouldn't that be just the same as checking the values that I am already checking them in the posted snipped above?

Comment: @Mel `const Foo = (props) => { console.log('whatever'); return <Form {...props} />`. Then just use the `Foo` component where you would use `Form`.

Comment: Thanks. Ill do some research on what that means next. Thank you. I have not found the entry point to understanding anything. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: You could, for testing purposes, add a dummy element and make the ```onClick``` event do what you want. For example: ```<div onClick={() => console.log("something")}> Console log test </div>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps conceptualize, here's a function you could use. I create a component which returns a div (in your case it would return a `Modal` component), passing on the children, but logging the `toLog` property before rendering the content. You could even pass a callback function instead of a variable explicitly to log. Hopefully this makes it more clear!

Something like this:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const LoggingModal = props => {
  console.log(props.toLog);
  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

const Example = () => {
  const [issueGroup, setIssueGroup] = useState(0);
  const incrementGroup = () => setIssueGroup(issueGroup + 1);
  return (
    <LoggingModal toLog={issueGroup}>
      <div onClick={incrementGroup}>On issue group {issueGroup}</div>
    </LoggingModal>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Example />
);
```

```css
* {
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Adding an attempted revision based on your edit:

```js
const CheckingModal = props => {
  const {modalPropsUpdate, title, toLog} = props;
  console.log("checking if modal knows the issue group: ", toLog);
  return (
    <Modal {...modalPropsUpdate} title={title}>
      {props.children}
    </Modal>
  );
};

//... then in use

<CheckingModal 
  modalPropsUpdate={modalPropsUpdate} 
  title="Update Issue Group"
  toLog={selectedIssueGroup}
  >
  <AdminUpdateIssueGroupForm
    onClose={modalPropsUpdate.onClose}
    issueGroup={selectedIssueGroup}
  />
</CheckingModal>
```

Comment: @Mel, happy to help. If you'd like any further explanation, let me know.

Comment: Thank you. I can see what you did works. I'll need to break it down slowly before I can bank it as understood. It's on my list for tonight. Thanks again.

Comment: hi again - I can follow the logic of what you did, but I either can't find a way to use it inside the form (position #3 in my updated post) or I am not using it correctly. Is there a way to check the id inside the form?

Comment: If this is just for debugging you could always use the [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) or an `onClick` event that logs things to the console. But if you want it to log with each render of the component, this is the way. If it's still unclear let me know! Good luck 